# How to find Xpath for this?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="50" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr class="TabUnselected" valign="top" id="MainTabControl2">
<td width="5"><img width="5" height="5" border="0" src="images\eyebrow-upper-left-corner.gif" style="border-width:0px;" /></td><td><table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" width="99%" border="0">
<tr>
<td class="TabCaption" align="left" valign="bottom" OnClick="selectTab(2, 11, 'MainTabControl', 'Panel', 'lblTitle', 'paneltitle', 'hfldSelectedTab');" OnMouseOver="highlightTab('MainTabControl2', 'TabUnselected', 'TabHighlighted');" OnMouseOut="resetTab('MainTabControl2', 'TabUnselected', 'TabHighlighted');" style="white-space:nowrap;">**More Details**</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to click the More Details (it seems to be a link).

I have tried using linkText but returns exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with link text == More Details (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 421 milliseconds
```

Is there anyway.. How to identify the xpath?

```
//*[@OnClick='selectTab(2, 11, 'MainTabControl', 'Panel', 'lblTitle', 'paneltitle', 'hfldSelectedTab')']
```

Tried this way by giving xpath.. No luck.. org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression '//*[@OnClick='selectTab(2, 11, 'MainTabControl', 'Panel', 'lblTitle', 'paneltitle', 'hfldSelectedTab')'] ' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 157 milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following xpath:

`//tr[@id='MainTabControl2']//td[@class='TabCaption']`

Or
`//td[@class='TabCaption']`

Edited:

If same id and class exists you can select with `text()` of the element as below:

`//td[contains(text(),'**More Details**')]`

Comment: Like More Details, it has 8 options and all has same id and class values.. will it work??

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //tr[@id='MainTabControl2']/td[@class='TabCaption'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 380 milliseconds

Comment: @ChanGan Please check my edited answer. Also please check the xpath which you posted just now

Comment: //td[contains(text(),'**More Details**')] is working